# How to define custom asserts that can enabled/disabled depending on a constant in Rust?

Tags: rust, macros

Some asserts are more computationally expensive than others, and I would like to have a way to enable/disable certain asserts. The asserts would be enabled/disabled depending on a compile-time constant. Conceptually this should be possible through the use of macros to simply omit code, but how can I do this in a clean way in Rust? (see below for my attempt that 'works' but seems messy)

For the sake of an example, I want to have code like this:

```
const MY_ASSERT_LEVEL = 1;

fn do_something_complicated(a: u32, b: u32) -> bool{
   false
}

let a = 5;
let b = 10;
assert_simple!(a != b);
assert_heavy!(do_something_complicated(a, b));
```

I want to have `assert_heavy` if `MY_ASSERT_LEVEL` is at least 2, and similarly I want `assert_simple` if `MY_ASSERT_LEVEL` is at least 1. For the case `MY_ASSERT_LEVEL == 0`, I want both asserts to be disabled.

My current solution is as follows:

I define in main.rs `const MY_ASSERT_LEVEL: u32 = 2`; and then I write in a separate file `my_asserts.rs`:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! assert_simple {
    ($($arg:tt)*) => {
        if $crate::MY_ASSERT_LEVEL >= 1 {
            assert!($($arg)*);
        }
    };

macro_rules! assert_heavy {
    ($($arg:tt)*) => {
        if $crate::MY_ASSERT_LEVEL >= 2 {
            assert!($($arg)*);
        }
    };
```

}

And this 'works', but it seems messy for several reasons:

1. `MY_ASSERT_LEVEL` is defined in the main file rather than in the same file as the assert macros. I tried moving `MY_ASSERT_LEVEL` into the macro file, but the compiler tells me that the `const MY_ASSERT_LEVEL` exists but is inaccessible to the macros.
2. I am exposing a global variable (`const MY ASSERT_LEVEL`) which has no role other than to define the macro levels. I would like to avoid this if possible.
3. When using the macros in other modules, I need to manually include each macro by writing e.g., `use crate::assert_simple`. Since in my use case I may have multiple assert macros, instead I would like to use some blanked statements like use `my_assert_macros::*` but not sure how to get this functionality.

I suspect I do not quite understand the macro syntax in Rust.

Can someone please help me? How I can implement the asserts I would like in a clean Rust way? I tried searching online to understand macros but this is as far as I could get.

Comment: You appear to understand macros just fine but have trouble with the module system. Do I understand you correctly that you want something like this: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3fcb98c4b717786a94afa2f4d28d0764)? You can imagine `mod my_asserts` to be a separate file.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link:https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=df2967aaf95d06f939a7f8e575b7ad8b

Comment: Thank you for looking into it! However I still have a problem when I move the my_asserts to a separate file, i.e., the const MY_ASSERT_LEVEL is inaccessible to the macros. Do you have an idea how to get around that? I also seem to need to explicitly call the macro with crate::assert_simple, too (e.g., in your playground example, one can remove the use::my_asserts::*, from my understanding it is not possible to write use::my_asserts::assert_simple, I suppouse one cannot include macros in 'use', but instead macros get somehow placed in the crate:: namespace?)

Comment: Where are you declaring `MY_ASSERT_LEVEL`? In main or in the module? Have you declared it as `pub(crate)`? And are you referencing it as `$crate::my_asserts::MY_ASSERT_LEVEL`? Have you declared the module in main with `mod my_asserts;`?

Comment: There is an other thing that is "wrong" here: it seems to me that you want to bundle asserts into production code. Since you want a "clean" Rust way, I'd suggest moving away from asserts and trying an other error handling design. If you still want asserts to ensure everything runs fine when you are running in debug mode, you can take a look at [debug_assert!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.debug_assert.html).

Comment: Regarding the scopes: instead of `#[macro_export]` you can use a regular re-export (although it has to come after the definition of the macros) like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=221e321775315c4ab25fdc03cd11114c

Comment: @isaactfa to answer your questions, I uploaded the code to a repo https://bitbucket.org/rustylurker/assert_example/src/master/ It does not compile. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @BlackBeans the point is to have the option to control whether or not to include 'heavy' debug asserts. The asserts should also be runnable in release mode, since debug mode is sometimes too slow to catch certain problems

Comment: @rusty_lurker You're doing a lot of unnecessary nesting here! A) Unless you plan to have a ton of features in `my_asserts` it doesn't need to be a directory with a `mod.rs`. It can just be a single file in the `src` directory. B) Inside `my_asserts.rs` don't define `mod my_asserts { ...`. The file will act as the module in and of itself as long as you declare it in main with `mod my_asserts`.

Comment: @rusty_lurker If you allow PRs on your bitbucket repo I can just submit one that works

Comment: @rusty_lurker I've submitted a PR

Comment: @isaactfa thank you, looks fantastic! I think this is what I was looking for. Can you post the repository as a new post, so that I can label it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done with the right file/module structure. Set your project up like this:

```
src
├─── main.rs
└─── my_asserts.rs
```

**`my_asserts.rs`**

```
pub(crate) const MY_ASSERT_LEVEL: u32 = 1;

macro_rules! assert_simple {
        ($($arg:tt)*) => {
            if $crate::my_asserts::MY_ASSERT_LEVEL >= 1 {
                assert!($($arg)*);
            }
        };
    }

macro_rules! assert_heavy {
        ($($arg:tt)*) => {
            if $crate::my_asserts::MY_ASSERT_LEVEL >= 2 {
                assert!($($arg)*);
            }
        };
    }

// these re-exports have to go after the macro definitions
pub(crate) use assert_heavy;
pub(crate) use assert_simple;
```

**`main.rs`**

```
use my_asserts::*;

mod my_asserts;

fn main() {
    assert_simple!(true);
    // this won't panic
    assert_heavy!(false);
}
```